# LINQ to HDInsight Hive table with Microsoft.Hadoop.Client

Tags: c#, linq, azure, hadoop, hive

According to [This Codeplex page](http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Simple%20Linq%20To%20Hive%20Query&referringTitle=LINQ%20to%20Hive) applying LINQ to hive table is possible in Azure HDInsight. But `HiveConnection` and `HiveRow` both types (as shown in the above mentioned example) are unavailable in [Microsoft.Hadoop.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Hadoop.Client/) nuget package. 
Do I need to Install the sdk from github source to apply LINQ to Hive?

Comment: Assuming your description and the results of Google search, yes, you have to install another <a href="https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Linq+to+hive">sdk</a>. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749872.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is the response I got from premium support:

- > HiveRow and HiveConnection are unavailable in
  >   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Hadoop.Client/ nuget package.
- > LINQ to HIVE as shown in Microsoft .NET SDK for Hadoop in Codeplex is
  >   part of an incubator project and not included in Azure HDInsight .NET
  >   SDK yet.

So as of now I can't use LINQ to query the HDInsight Hive table via the official sdk. It is possible with the incubator project [Microsoft.Hadoop.Hive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Hadoop.Hive/)